# Deriving Itō's Process with a drift for Geometric Brownian Process

Tags: stochastic-processes

Can anyone show how to derive Itō's Process if given a Geometric Brownian Process $\Delta S/S=\mu\Delta t + \sigma\epsilon\sqrt{\Delta t}$, where $\Delta S$ = change in stock price, $\mu$=expected rate of return, $\sigma$=volatility of stock, $ε\sim \mathrm{N}(0,1)$, and $\sigma\epsilon\sqrt{\Delta t}$ as stochastic companion? I found a lot of resources online that mention Itō's Lemma in detail, but not really Itō's Process (maybe I miss some good resources). I'm a bit confused between the two.

Answer (score 0):

An [Ito Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D_calculus#It.C5.8D_processes) is just a particular type of semi-martingale.
Ito's lemma applies to semi-martingales with specific integrability hypothesis that are here trivially met ( but check it! )

Now the "hard" part of all these Stochastic Equations is somehow guessing the correct function to apply Ito's lemma to. I'm not aware of any general method, I know there is some kind of heuristic stochastic variation of constant method but even simple equations like that do not have a general solving algorithm like in the deterministic case

But you can always try to guess with experience !

In your case $\frac{\mathrm{d} S}{S}$ looks a lot like what you would have if you were to differentiate $\log S$ so why not try to apply Ito's lemma to $\log S_t$